# Rendering and embedding Rmarkdown in an email for microsoft outlook

Tags: css, r, email, r-markdown, blastula

I have been trying to render an Rmarkdown file and send the output embedded in an email to a Microsoft outlook email.

Any help with this problem would be great appreciated!

I have tried using both the emayili and blastula packages.

While the emayili package sends perfectly to a gmail account the formatting is inconsistent (graphs misaligned, bullet points squeezed together etc.). I believe this is an issue with the different treatment of CSS formatting in gmail and outlook.

The blastula package will format the text correctly however the graphs (ggplots) do not remain embedded in the body of the email and instead show up only as attachments (this happens in both the outlook and gmail emails).

Comment: If You're using gmail to send mails try **gmailr** package

Comment: Gave it a go using the gmailr package unfortunately it was the same problem encountered when using the emayili package

Comment: When You're using `gmailr`, you don't need **`emayili`**.